# Vaadin Grid with CallbackDataProvider always throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin22

I am trying to optimize the loading of a *big* table in my application into a `com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid`. For that - instead of passing the entire, huge `List<HistoryElement>` using `grid.setItems(allData)` (which always caused lengthy freezing of the UI) - I am now using a `CallbackDataProvider`, that's returning the elements between `offset` and `offset + limit` as a `Stream<HistoryElement>`. The implementation is very similar to the example here: [How to Vaadin CallbackDataProvider make an asyncronous fetch data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942097/how-to-vaadin-callbackdataprovider-make-an-asyncronous-fetch-data), i.e. I always create a Stream from a fraction (a `sublist(...)`) of the entire list.

In principle this seems to works except each time when I scroll towards the end of the list, i.e. when the `offset + limit` reaches the maximum of available elements. At that point I always get a huge exception stack trace like below (only the offending index varies).

But: there is not a single line of my own code in that trace! How can I avoid this `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? WHat might I be doing wrong here that later triggers that exception?   Or could it be that the index calculation inside the `Grid`-widget is faulty?
Any hints would be appreciated!

This is using Vaadin v22.0.2 and Java 11.

```
...
2022-01-03 13:34:16,324 ERROR [http-nio-8085-exec-5] com.vaadin.flow.server.DefaultErrorHandler:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 133 out of bounds for length 133
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.lambda$getJsonItems$5(DataCommunicator.java:1326)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:104)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:699)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.getJsonItems(DataCommunicator.java:1328)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.lambda$collectChangesToSend$4(DataCommunicator.java:1281)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.applyIfNotEmpty(DataCommunicator.java:1341)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.withMissing(DataCommunicator.java:1336)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.collectChangesToSend(DataCommunicator.java:1280)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.flush(DataCommunicator.java:1152)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.lambda$requestFlush$7258256f$1(DataCommunicator.java:1069)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree.lambda$runExecutionsBeforeClientResponse$2(StateTree.java:392)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree.runExecutionsBeforeClientResponse(StateTree.java:389)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlWriter.encodeChanges(UidlWriter.java:391)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlWriter.createUidl(UidlWriter.java:174)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.createUidl(UidlRequestHandler.java:158)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.writeUidl(UidlRequestHandler.java:146)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:116)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1567)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:299)
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:109)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: How is equals and hashCode of HistoryElement implemented?

Comment: @Anna Koskinen Sorry - only came around to continue on my pet project now. The equals and hashcode are implemented using lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason! The CallbackDataProvider has to implement two methods, one providing a count of all available items and the other that allows the widget to request a chunk of data. In my case - due to a wrong argument passed to the underlying filtering done by the service that provides the count as well as the data - the count did not always match the number of items actually retrievable. That mismatch obviously caused the widget to throw these IndexOutOfBounds exceptions. My bad...